# How to solve lifetime problems when building a composite object holding pointers to objects is composed by

Tags: c++, inheritance, math

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54347416/stdfunction-bad-memory-access-when-creating-a-temporary) other one. I'm trying to implement the `virtual method` approach suggested in one of the answers.

I have an abstract base class representing an object described by a Level-Set function

```
    class LevelSetObject
    {

    public:
        virtual double SDF(double x, double y, double z) const = 0;


        /** @brief Union of two LevelSetObjects */
        CompositeLevelSetObject operator+(LevelSetObject& other);


        virtual ~LevelSetObject() = default;

    };
```

The first implementation I had with `std::function` was working more or less as expected. The difference now is that I return a `CompositeLevelSetObject` when adding up two generic `LevelSetObjects`

```
       CompositeLevelSetObject LevelSetObject::operator+(LevelSetObject& other)  {
            CompositeFun* fun = [] (double sdf_value1, double sdf_value2) {
                return std::min(sdf_value1, sdf_value2);
            };

            auto first = std::unique_ptr<LevelSetObject>(new LevelSetObject(*this));
            auto second = std::unique_ptr<LevelSetObject>(new LevelSetObject(other));

            return { std::move(first), std::move(second), fun };
        }
```

A `CompositeLevelSetObject`, at least in my mind :), is an object that takes as input pointers 
the two objects it's composed by, plus a function pointer that computes the resulting distance function (Primitive combinations of `LevelSetObjects` are encoded by operations between the two single distance function of the objects [ref ("Primitive Combinations")](https://iquilezles.org/www/articles/distfunctions/distfunctions.htm))

```
    /** @brief This is the function that is called on the two single SDF function of the objects */
    using CompositeFun = double (double, double);


    /**
     * @brief A class representing a composite LevelSetObject coming out of operation between two other LevelSetObjects
     *
     * This class stores pointers to the two LevelSetObject and executes a given function on both of them
     */
    class CompositeLevelSetObject : public LevelSetObject
    {

    using LevelSetObjectPtr = std::unique_ptr<LevelSetObject>;

    private:
        LevelSetObjectPtr m_first;
        LevelSetObjectPtr m_second;
        CompositeFun* m_fun;


    public:
        CompositeLevelSetObject() = default;
        CompositeLevelSetObject(LevelSetObjectPtr first, LevelSetObjectPtr second, CompositeFun* m_fun);
        CompositeLevelSetObject(CompositeLevelSetObject&&);

        double SDF(double x, double y, double z) const override;

        // :: Operators ::
        CompositeLevelSetObject& operator=(CompositeLevelSetObject&&);
    };
}

    double CompositeLevelSetObject::SDF(double x, double y, double z) const {
        return m_fun(m_first->SDF(x, y, z), m_second->SDF(x, y, z));
    }
```

This clearly does not work, because in the `LevelSetObject::operator+`, I'm creating the pointers instantiating an abstract class.

```
allocating an object of abstract class type 'hgve::LevelSetObject'
            auto first = std::unique_ptr<LevelSetObject>(new LevelSetObject(*this));
```

So I tried to switch the `LevelSetObject::SDF` method to be non-pure, returning `0`. But clearly doesn't work because then everything returns 0.

I'm missing something in my conceptual organisation of the data structure, probably due to my dynamic languages background, but I can't see it. Any help is appreciated.

An example of usage:

```
// Vector containing a list of LevelSetSpheres
static std::vector<LevelSetSphere> elements = {
    LevelSetSphere{radius, {radius, 0.25, 0.25}},
    LevelSetSphere{radius, {radius + interDistance, 0.25, 0.25}},
    LevelSetSphere{radius, {radius + 2*interDistance, 0.25, 0.25}}
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // Sum first two elements
    CompositeLevelSetObject soot = elements[0] + elements[1];
    for(auto el = std::next(elements.begin(), 2); el != elements.end(); ++el) {
        // Combine elements
        soot = soot + *el;
    }
}
```

`LevelSetSphere` is a derived class from `LevelSetObject`.

```
    class LevelSetSphere : public LevelSetObject
    {
    private:
        double m_R; /**< The radius of the sphere */
        SimpleVector m_C; /**< The center of the sphere */

    public:
        /** @brief Constructor
         *
         *  @param  radius      The radius of the sphere
         */
        LevelSetSphere(double radius, SimpleVector center);

        double SDF(double x, double y, double z) const override;
    };
```

Comment: Can you give an example showing how these objects are created and how the `operator+` is used, please? (e.g. a function that creates some LevelSetObjects and combines them)

Comment: Perhaps [CRTP (Curiously Recurring Template Pattern)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) could help?

Comment: @user253751 I added an usage example and details on the errors I am getting.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I thought about it.  `LevelSetObject` probably needs to depend on two template parameters, let's say `Derived` for the CRTP, `Other` for the input argument of the `operator+` method. I was not able to make it work since `LevelSetObject` and `CompositeLevelSetObject` depend on each other -> Circular dependency of header files + templates.

Comment: I don't think templates will help you with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `new LevelSetObject`, this creates a new object whose type is LevelSetObject. Seems obvious, but it needs to be pointed out.

You don't want a new `LevelSetObject`, you want a new `LevelSetSphere` (if the input object is a sphere).

You can take a `LevelSetObject` and transfer ownership to a `unique_ptr` without copying, but you have to be careful with the ownership. If you want to do this, it's better to use a `unique_ptr` from the start (option 3). You can only transfer ownership if the object was created with `new`. Local variables, global variables, and elements of vectors (like in your example), among other things, can't be transferred to `unique_ptr`. Only objects created with `new`.

Here are three possible solutions:

1. Add a `virtual std::unique_ptr<LevelSetObject> copy() const = 0;` method to `LevelSetObject`. (Implement this in every derived class, so it makes a copy)
2. Make the CompositeLevelSet object point to the original `LevelSetObject`s instead of copying them. This means you can't use the composite object after the original objects are destroyed. It also means the intermediate compositions need to be saved somewhere. Not a great option.
3. Pass ownership into `operator+` so that it doesn't need to copy the objects. For example, define a `unique_ptr<CompositeLevelSetObject> operator+(unique_ptr<LevelSetObject> left, unique_ptr<LevelSetObject> right)`. (If this confuses you, it can be a function instead of an operator)

Comment: I would rename `copy` into `clone`.

Comment: I opted for option 1) since it looked the easiest one to use on the user side. The only addition to that I had to apply is to switch `LevelSetObjectPtr` to use `shared_ptr`, since also `CompositeLevelSetObject` is a child of `LevelSetObject` and needs to be copied.